# Short story, first spaceship's burn starts chain reaction and destroys all life, astronaut returns and seeks out the ocean

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, apocalypse

I think (but I'm not sure) this story is quite old, possibly from before the first launch of anything into space. In the story the burn from the shuttle/spacecraft leaving Earth sets off a chain reaction that destroys all life on Earth. When the astronaut aboard returns to Earth, he realizes he is all that is left, and has an urge to find the ocean.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Alfred Bester, "[Adam and No Eve](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46436)"

The protagonist develops a drive that uses a "catalyst on iron solution." There is a pit that is supposed to contain any exhaust spillage until the ship is in space.  This safety feature doesn't work -oops- and the first launch destroys the Earth.

> And then he knew what had brought him back to the sea.  There need be
> no Adam - no Eve.  Only the sea, the great mother of life was needed.

Comment: So the spaceship was designed was software engineers? Nyah nyah nyah (time to hide)

Comment: People in the story are literally trying to kill the protagonist and destroy the ship because it's such a bad idea.  But he presses on.

Comment: Thanks @Organic Marble, that puts it in an entirely new light

Comment: @OrganicMarble *closes eyes tightly* I won't make a comparison to current US politics... I won't make a comparison to US politics...

Comment: @corsiKa You refer to the battle for the presidency between chaotic neutral and lawless evil?

Comment: @user14111 Well, it's confusing to say the least.